# How to update by order

Tags: django, django-models, sql-update, sql-order-by

I have a django application with a model. I need to update the model objects according to ascending id. Something like this.

```
MyModel.objects.filter(my_field='value').order_by("id").update(another_field='anotheValue')
```

Can i be assure that the update will happen by the order according to the order by?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already ordered the query set using id, it should update sequentially.

From the docs,

> Using update() also prevents a race condition wherein something might
>   change in your database in the short period of time between loading
>   the object and calling save().

So I think the ordering might not matter.  However to be perfectly sure, you can iterate over the items and update them:

```
rows = MyModel.objects.filter(my_field='value').order_by("id")
for row in rows:
    row.another_field = 'another value'
    row.save()
```

However, the `update` method would generate one SQL query, where as the iteration would generate many. So this might be an issue with performance.